# Prevent moving text elements on hover which is +1px font size

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hover, font-size

I have a row with text elements, in this case they are named "categories", any category that is on hover gets added a class that has font-size 1px bigger than non hover. Font size of my category may be diffrent (all categories have the same font but in config it can be changed) and comes from outside config.

```
const currentCategoryStyle = {
    fontSize: `${parseInt(singleCategory['font-size'].replace('px', '')) + 1}px`,
  };

 <div className="categories-container d-flex">
            {categories.map(category => (
              <div
                className="single-category"
                onMouseEnter={() => {
                  setCategoryHover(category.id);
                }}
                onMouseLeave={() => {
                  setCategoryHover(null);
                }}
                style={{
                  ...(
                    categoryHover === category.id  &&
                    currentCategoryStyle),
                }}
              >
                {category.name}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
```

But the problem is, that every element moves a bit, when I hover one category, of course because it gets bigger. My question is, what can I do to prevent this? Margin, padding doesn't really work here, any ideas?

Comment: box-sizing: border-box; and/or specify the width explicitly.

Comment: Could you create [a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net)?